# Adding many items with AddToCollection in WF4 (workflow)

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I am using a List (Of String) in WF4 because I'd like to perform set operations (like get distinct, etc.) and had a qs. about using the AddToCollection activity. Is it possible to add a number of items with one statement?
e.g. I'd like to add "alpha", "bravo", "charlie" in one activity instead of three

The Collection - String does not work well for me because I cannot get it in the C# call in the client. I could use that too if you have a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the built-in AddToCollection activity only supports adding one at a time. Most likely this is because it uses the [IList interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) which doesn't offer a method to add items in bulk unlike List which has [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx). You should be able to write an AddManyToList activity very easily. Here's some sample code to get you goin:

```
public sealed class AddManyToList<T> : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<List<T>> List
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<IEnumerable<T>> Items
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    public override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
       this.List.Get(context).AddRange(this.Items.Get(context))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a code activity  then there is a short-cut (I am using it)

Use an Assign Activity to assign the variable as follows

```
  names = names.Union(New String()
    {"alpha","bravo","charlie"}).ToList()
```

Comment: This seems like what's really being asked for: adding a list to a list. I like it.